# Accessing Character Data In XML With A Stylesheet (XSLT)

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an xml file that holds some html-code in an element. The html elements however are escaped, either declared as CDATA or with entities for '<' and '>'.

Therefore i can't simply match these elements with the xsl-element 'template'. 
I want to access and modify the html elements and their attributes with my stylesheet and i  know that anyhow this is possible, however I couldn't find a way how to do it yet.

I would really appreciate your help as I'm dealing for quite a long time with this problem.
Thank you very much in advance!

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Master>
 <Content>
  <SomeHTML> &lt; img src="./world.jpg" &gt;  
             <!-- This is one out of many other html elements I want to access -->
  </SomeHTML>
 </Content
</Master>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use an extension function to parse the text inside of `<SomeHTML>`, pass that onto templates (maybe using a different mode) and finally use `<xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="true"/>` for your output.

The extension function must of course be supported by your parser, which means that you are constrained by either your parser or your environment that may not allow installing and/or using such extension functions for various reasons:

- An Extension function for Java's Standard XSLT infrastructure is given in http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10464_05/web.904/b12099/adx04xsl.htm#1008934
- Saxon has [saxon:parse(string)](http://saxon.sourceforge.net/saxon7.2/extensions.html#parse), but according to the documentation this is limited to well-formed XML - as far as I can see from your example, you don't have that.

Comment: Actually I am using a third party software that creates a PDF with the processor of Ibex ('Ibex PDF Creator'). The software supports the use of a custom stylesheet to modify the layout of the PDF. There is a default stylesheet as well that i can neither edit nor open as it is part of the source code. However the default stylesheet in some way manages to access the character data as the PDF contains all html data from the xml.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's impossible in pure XSLT, because the character data is a regular text, not html, so you could process it as usual text with string functions (e.g. substring). You have to use an extension with HTML parser. It is processor specific.

The html should be stored in the XML file as tags in first place (but of course as XHTML, so that `<img>` tag must be closed or used as empty `<img/>`).

Answer (score 1):

Which XSLT processor do you use? For instance with Saxon 9 you could use an extension function like http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/extensions/functions/parse-html.xml.

Comment: I am using a third party software that uses the Ibex PDF Creator. I couldn't find a suitable extension function however.